# B2B installation in Magento 2.4.5-p1 EE

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.4

unable to install b2b magento extension in Default Magento 2.4.5-p1 EE.[image]

Comment: which steps you are trying? can you add to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install B2B as below:

```
composer require magento/extension-b2b --no-update
composer update
```

For Adobe Commerce 2.4.5-p1, this will install version 1.3.4-p1 of the B2B module.

Alternatively, you should be able to install the module by specifying that version when you require the module.

```
composer require magento/extension-b2b:1.3.4-p1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your these things :

```
- PHP version compitability
- Composer.json and Composer.lock
```

If you need more help please let me know

Comment: i had checked but idk what to do

Answer (score 0):

`composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition:2.4.5-p1 magento/extension-b2b --with-all-dependencies` worked for me.